# OSQL RTM on SQL Server 2012 SP2?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a situation that I've never seen.  OSQL crashed in a scheduled job which has always worked.  Windows event viewer shows an exception code: 0xc0000005.
the version of OSQL.exe also showing in the same Windows Event Viewer error message is 2011.110.2100.60. -->  this corresponds to the SQL Server 2012 RTM.

When running @@version of the SQL Server it states that I have SP2 installed.

Is this normal? do I need to upgrade OSQL to SP2? If so, how to upgrade OSQL to SP2?

OSQL Windows Event Viewer output:

```
    Faulting application name: OSQL.EXE, version: 2011.110.2100.60, time stamp: 0x4f35eaf3
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18696, time stamp: 0x59153753
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000546fb
Faulting process id: 0x1bdc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d31d465269cf58
Faulting application path: \\SFSMSSQL\c$\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\OSQL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 5bb47a06-895c-11e7-80eb-005056b410f0
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

@@Version output:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64) 
                May 14 2014 18:34:29 
                Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
                Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Added Note: I am aware that we should be using SQLCMD instead OSQL which will soon be depricated... it is in our road map. .

My research hasn't been fruitful.

Thank you

Comment: Wow `osql`, that's a name I've not heard in a very long time. I didn't realize that it still shipped. That being said, it's deprecated, you should move to `sqlcmd` instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/osql-utility

Comment: @Nic It's in our plans... Since it's a software that's been around for over 25 years it's not as simple as we would like it to be.

Answer (score 2):

> Faulting application path: \SFSMSSQL\c$\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\OSQL.EXE
>
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

You appear to be running osql.exe from another server via the c$ share.  If so, the local ntdll.dll is probably a different version to the osql.exe on the remote server.

Change the path

```
\\SFSMSSQL\c$\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\OSQL.EXE
```

to something like:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\OSQL.EXE
```

Comment: Didn't notice that, I will try that.